# How does R reference unassigned values?

Tags: r, memory-management

I'm familiar with `tracemem()` showing the hex memory address of an assigned variable, e.g.

```r
x <- 2
tracemem(x)
#> [1] "<0x876df68>"
```

but what does this involve (under the hood) when the value is literally just an unassigned value? e.g.

```r
tracemem(4)
#> [1] "<0x9bd93b8>"
```

The same question applies to just evaluating an expression without assignment

```r
4
#> [1] 4
```

It seems that if I evaluate this several times in the console, I get ever-increasing hex addresses

```r
tracemem(4)
#> [1] "<0x8779968>"
tracemem(4)
#> [1] "<0x87799c8>"
tracemem(4)
#> [1] "<0x8779a28>"
```

but if I either explicitly loop this operation

```r
for ( i in 1:3 ) { print(tracemem(4)) }
#> [1] "<0x28bda48>"
#> [1] "<0x28bda48>"
#> [1] "<0x28bda48>"
```

or with `sapply` via `replicate`

```r
replicate(3, tracemem(4))
#> [1] "<0xba88208>" "<0xba88208>" "<0xba88208>"
```

I get repeats of the same address, even if I explicitly delay the printing between iterations

```r
for ( i in 1:3 ) { print(tracemem(4)); Sys.sleep(1) }
#> [1] "<0xa3c4058>"
#> [1] "<0xa3c4058>"
#> [1] "<0xa3c4058>"
```

My best guess is that the call refers to an already temporarily assigned value in the `parent.frame` given `eval.parent(substitute(` in `replicate`,  but I don't know enough about the underlying `.Primitive` code of `for` to know if it's doing the same there.

I have some confidence that `R` is creating temporary variables given that I can do

```r
list(x = 1)
#> $x
#> [1] 1
```

so `R` must be processing the data even though it never assigns to anything. I'm aware of the strict formality summarised by @hadleywickham's tweet:

[image]

but I'm not sure how it works here. Is it just that the temporary name isn't preserved? Does the `for` loop always use that name/object? Does evaluating lots of code regardless of whether or not it's assigned still use up memory? (up until `gc()` is called, whenever that is??)

tl;dr -- how does `R` "store" unassigned values for printing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I will do what I can here.

First off, tracemem is a *primitive*. This means it is not a closure like the vast majority of R-level functions you can call from R code. More specifically, it is a BUILTINSXP primitive:

```
> .Internal(inspect(tracemem))
@62f548 08 BUILTINSXP g0c0 [MARK,NAM(1)]
```

This means that when it is called, a *closure* is NOT applied (because it is a primitive) and it's argument IS evaluated, because it is a BUILTINSXP (see [this section of the R internals manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Argument-evaluation)).

Closure application is when R objects passed as arguments in function calls are assigned to the appropriate variables within the call frame. Thus this doesn't happen for tracemem. Instead, its arguments are evaluated at the C level into a SEXP that is never bound to any symbol in any environment, but instead is passed directly to the C-level do_tracemem function. See [this line within the C-level eval function](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/0807e5cedc97cdc5ff0a9171f7e0f18349cda64b/src/main/eval.c#L716)

This means that when a numeric constant is passed to tracemem (a valid call though something one would generally not have any reason to do), you get the actual SEXP for the constant, not one representing an R level variable with the value 4, being passed down to do_tracemem.

As far as I can tell, within any evaluation frame (I may not be using this term precisely, but call frames and steps within a for loop qualify, as do individual top-level expressions) , every evaluation of , e.g., "4L" gets an entirely new SEXP (INTSXP, speciifically) with NAMED set immediately to 4. Between these frames, it appears that they can be shared, though I pretty strongly suspect that may be an artifact of memory-reuse rather than actually shared SEXPs.

The output below appears to corroborate the memory-reuse theory but I don't have the cycles free to confirm it beyond that at the moment.

```
> for(i in 1:3) {print(tracemem(4L)); print(tracemem(4L))}
[1] "<0x1c3f3b8>"
[1] "<0x1c3f328>"
[1] "<0x1c3f3b8>"
[1] "<0x1c3f328>"
[1] "<0x1c3f3b8>"
[1] "<0x1c3f328>"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful and detailed answer. Additionally, substituting a non-constant structure into `tracemem` seems to do what I would expect e.g. `print(tracemem(c(5L)))` in the loop gives a different address for every call, presumably because (if I follow your answer right) it is now evaluated with a copy each iteration due to being a closure evaluation (and thus NAMED is incremented in `do_for`).